# What are the job prospects in supply chain management with a postgraduate diploma in canada?

Tags: canada, student-visa, study, career

I am a prospective international student and I am interested in pursuing a postgraduate diploma in supply chain management.  I already have a  degree in international relations. I wanted to find out whether supply chain management is an in demand sector in canada. And what are the job prospects with regards to postgraduate diploma in supply chain management?

Comment: What has your own research on this topic revealed?